# Книги по SQL-синтаксису и его параметрам

Tags: sql, книги, 1с

Здравствуйте, многоуважаемые пользователи и программисты программы 1С 8.2.

Я являюсь новичком в программировании в конфигурации 1С 8.2 и у меня сразу возникает такой вопрос после того, как я просмотрел и прочитал некоторые книги и статьи. Я не нашел нормального описания запросов и параметров.

Не могли вы бы мне посоветовать какие-нибудь книги и статьи.

Comment: Мои глаза!!! отредактируйте вопрос!

Comment: мои не выдержали =)

Answer (score 3):

Воспользуйтесь конструктором запросов, синтаксис во многом похож на SQL (если не обращать особого внимания на русский язык), но есть и отличия, расширения языка запросов в зависимости от вида метаданных.

- [Книги по платформе](http://v8.1c.ru/metod/books/)
- [Раздел по 1С 8 на мисте](http://kb.mista.ru/index.php?forum=1c&v8=1)

Answer (score 0):

[Вот здесь](http://sql.itsoft.ru/) все есть, но очень официально, а вот [здесь](http://www.artfulsoftware.com/infotree/queries.php?&bw=1267) масса конкретных примеров SQL-запросов, изучив которые можно стать гуру.

Comment: Для 1С эти ссылки не годятся. совсем.

Comment: Вы меня преследуете

Comment: Просто 1С - это слишком причудливый фреймворк. Знание sql помогает в составлении запросов, но в качестве справочной информации те ссылки, которые Вы привели не подходят.
Просто поправка. Ничего личного :)